# Angular2 HTTP: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http, polyfills, angular2-routing

So Im practicing http post and get methods of Angular2 from YouTube tutorial and I cant figure out the problem
Here is my index.html files:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTodo App</title>

<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>   
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
System.import('app.js')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
    <http-comp>Loading..</http-comp>
</body>
</html>
```

This is http service file:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' ;

@Injectable()
export class webhttpservice{

constructor(private http : Http){}

getfunctionfromapp(){
   return this.http.get('www.google.com')
              .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

Here is app.ts file:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { webhttpservice } from './httpService';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
selector : 'http-comp',
template : `

<button (click) = 'reqfunction()'>Get Request</button>
<p></p>
<br>
<button>Post Request</button>
<p></p>

`,
providers : [webhttpservice]
})
export class httpcomponent{

getdata;
constructor(private var1: webhttpservice){}
reqfunction(){
    this.var1.getfunctionfromapp()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.getdata = JSON.stringify(data),
                error => alert(error),
                () => console.log('Finished')

            );
}

}
```

bootstrap(httpcomponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);

These are the original errors Im getting

```
>Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)  
httpService:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <__exec @ 
angular2-polyfills.js:138   
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/httpService
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app.jsrun
@ angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-
```

Comment: `www.google.com` can't say if you have url like it.

Comment: I supposed get as request to url, so does it matter requesting www.google.com or from service etc, Is it right?

Comment: what i meant was url without protocols.

Comment: It will trigger when we click on button but for this first button(interface) should be shown, and its not happening, all the errors Im getting is related to polyfills and browser responded with Loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to load the TypeScript file containing your `webhttpservice` class is a bit strange:

> Evaluating http://localhost:3000/httpService

It should be: http://localhost:3000/app/httpService.js with your configuration...

Do you put the `httpService.ts` file under the `app` folder? According to your SystemJS configuration, you should.

Comment: I'm not following any structure its just all files at root no folders any, no i didnt specify http://localhost:3000/httpService anywhere :( all the errors are related to polyfilles,

Comment: That's the problem in fact. Because in your SystemJS configuration, you configure the `app` package. This tells your application to load transpiled files (for example `httpService.js` for `httpService.ts`) when doing an import (for example `import { webhttpservice } from './httpService';`). You can't define this rule at the root level otherwise angular2 modules will be also loaded using this strategy...

Comment: So what should i do now, because its first time Im practicing http and have been followed this structure from beginning

Comment: You only thing you miss here I think is to put all the TypeScript files of your application under an `app` sub folder ;-)

Comment: ahhh why is it to be done when doing some http stuff?

Comment: It's not related to HTTP in particular but how module support works. But SystemJS will load your module using HTTP. For example `import { webhttpservice } from './httpService';` call `http://(...)/app/httpService.js` (according to your SystemJS configuration i.e. `System.config(...)`)

Comment: yes it worked, and how can i change systemjs configuration so that it load from simple structure not from app folder

Comment: Im getting this error I changed nothing: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://date.jsontest.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

Comment: It's something normal since you try to do an AJAX request on another domain (www.google.com). In this case, you need to leverage CORS (cf this link: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/). But I'm pretty sure www.google.com isn't CORS compliant ;-) However this tells us that the request is sent so your `webhttpservice` is loaded and its processing correctly executed!

Comment: getfunctionfromapp(){
       return this.http.get("http://time.jsontest.com")
                  .map(res => res.json());
    }

Comment: It's the same since the domain of your Angular2 application is `localhost:3000` ;-) It's a server-side problem not a client-side one... You can check the Network tab within dev tools of your browser. I'm sure that won't see any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response headers.

Comment: You need to update the server application to return this header in the response. There is nothing you can do in the Angular application...